# Why does onerror event not work for img tag when jquery is put in footer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Consider the following example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    img {
      max-width:600px;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planwall.com/lk.jpg" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planwer.com/my.jpg" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.plwallpaper.com/static/images/slkdl.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.pnwallpaper.com/static/images/er5.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planwlpaper.com/static/images/3col.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planaper.com/sttic/images/fghdfg.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.pwalper.com/sttic/imaes/3dsfgdg45.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/34rt5.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planwaaper.com/static/images/7004205-cool-black-backgrounds-27640_lhK8IKI.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.wallpeast.com/wallpaper-cool/page/4#static/images/free-cool-wallpaper-17426-18158-hd-wallpapers.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <script>  
  /*
    for(var i=0; i<document.getElementsByTagName("img").length; i++) {      
      document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].addEventListener("error", function() {
        this.src = "https://cdn.colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/404-not-found-error-page-examples.png";        
      });      
    }
    */   
  </script>
  <script>

   $(document).ready(function(){  
    $("img").on("error", function(){
      $(this).attr( "src", "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/error-icon-28.png" );      
    });
  });

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

All the images have wrong url by default. The `error` event is assigned to all the `img` tags. The `src` of images that get error is changed. Everything works fine. The problem is if I put jquery cdn in the footer then the src attribute is not replaced. Example below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    img {
      max-width:600px;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planwall.com/lk.jpg" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planwer.com/my.jpg" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.plwallpaper.com/static/images/slkdl.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.pnwallpaper.com/static/images/er5.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planwlpaper.com/static/images/3col.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planaper.com/sttic/images/fghdfg.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.pwalper.com/sttic/imaes/3dsfgdg45.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/34rt5.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planwaaper.com/static/images/7004205-cool-black-backgrounds-27640_lhK8IKI.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.wallpeast.com/wallpaper-cool/page/4#static/images/free-cool-wallpaper-17426-18158-hd-wallpapers.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <script>  
  /*
    for(var i=0; i<document.getElementsByTagName("img").length; i++) {      
      document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].addEventListener("error", function() {
        this.src = "https://cdn.colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/404-not-found-error-page-examples.png";        
      });      
    }
    */   
  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script> 
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){  
    $("img").on("error", function(){      
      $(this).attr( "src", "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/error-icon-28.png" );  
    });
  });

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

The question is simple:

> Why does `onerror` event not work for `img` tag when jquery is put in the footer?

When I look into the console then out of 10 only 3 or 4 images have received error others are appended with `[18ms]` or some other time like `[21ms] etc.

Comment: It's because the request to load the image has already been made. You can't attach an event handler for existing requests. The reason you get only a few errors in the console is because the browser is limited to loading a certain amount of images at one time (between 5-20 depending on browser and settings) therefore any images requested *after* the script has been loaded (ie. those not in the first batch) will have the `error` handler attached

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan But what does it have to do with jquery cdn link being in footer or header? And when jquery is in header even then I have put the `error` event in the footer. So then why does the event get attached even after the request to load image has been made?

Comment: It's because document.ready fires when the DOM is completely loaded. `img` elements will request their images as soon as they are loaded, ie. before document.ready has fired. Hence the event handler is not placed on them at that point

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I thing you misunderstood me. In my first example link to jquery library is placed in the header. The event handler script is always in the footer. Moreover the event handler is inside dom ready. Then why does the image src get replaced? Why is `error` handler attached to all the images even after `img` tags have been parsed?

Comment: No misunderstanding. It's all to do with the page lifecycle. It goes like this: DOM begins to be created -> jQuery loaded -> `img` elements loaded and their `src` URL is requested -> DOM finishes loading -> document.ready fires -> your jQuery code is executed. Hence the first batch of `img` elements have requested their images without your jQuery code being attached to them. Hopefully that's clearer now.

Comment: To fix this the best method is to (unfortunately) use an `onerror` attribute. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan "_Hence the first batch of `img` elements have requested their images without your jQuery code being attached to them_" -- Then why does their `src` attributes get changed?

Answer (score 2):

Your code is not working since the error events are raised before your jquery handlers are bound.

The browser loads the item as they are found in the dom. So when you add the jquery script at the end. The browser will already have started loading the img tags that is above them. By the time the jQuery is loaded parsed and your document is ready and your handler is bound most of your images would have already been error-ed or loaded.

The below code Will work since after document is ready it creates an in-memory img items to check if the images are loaded properly. Additional images if added will be handled by the handler.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    img {
      max-width:600px;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planwall.com/lk.jpg" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planwer.com/my.jpg" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.plwallpaper.com/static/images/slkdl.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.pnwallpaper.com/static/images/er5.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planwlpaper.com/static/images/3col.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planaper.com/sttic/images/fghdfg.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.pwalper.com/sttic/imaes/3dsfgdg45.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/34rt5.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planwaaper.com/static/images/7004205-cool-black-backgrounds-27640_lhK8IKI.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.wallpeast.com/wallpaper-cool/page/4#static/images/free-cool-wallpaper-17426-18158-hd-wallpapers.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <script>  
  /*
    for(var i=0; i<document.getElementsByTagName("img").length; i++) {      
      document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].addEventListener("error", function() {
        this.src = "https://cdn.colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/404-not-found-error-page-examples.png";        
      });      
    }
    */   
  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script> 
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){  
     $("img").each(function(i,ele){
        $("<img/>").attr("src",$(ele).attr("src")).on('error', function() {             
            $(ele).attr( "src", "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/error-icon-28.png" );
         })
     });
     
    $("img").on("error", function(){      
      $(this).attr( "src", "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/error-icon-28.png" );  
    });
  });

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I guess when jquery cdn is put into the `footer` then the browser spend some time in downloading that. In that time `img` tags send requests. On the other hand if jquery cdn is in the `head` then `dom` gets ready before `img` tags could get error(finish sending request?).

Comment: By the way when we create an image tag with jquery and assign it's `src` the image that has already been downloaded. Does the browser downloads the same image twice? Or does it uses the cached one?

Comment: Why did you use `$("img").on("error", function(){      
      $(this).attr( "src", "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/error-icon-28.png" );  
    });` at last? Aren't all image tags checked before this code already?

Comment: How is `ele` parameter acting like `this`? And what is the purpose of `i` paramenter? Is it the `event` parameter?

Comment: @user31782 check jquery each api https://api.jquery.com/each/ ele is the current element and i is the index.
Why i attached $("img").on("error") was by mistake if it was added like $(document).on("error","img",function) then you can use the handler for new images injected into the dom later by js.

Comment: @user31782 when we create an image tag with jquery. it will download the image again. but usually images are cached by browser so there will not be a second network call.Try running the snippet i have created with chrome network tab open and you will see that img are requested only once.

Answer (score -4):

jquery using with class 
so you can use .myimage

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <style>
    img {
      max-width:600px;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planwall.com/lk.jpg" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planwer.com/my.jpg" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.plwallpaper.com/static/images/slkdl.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.pnwallpaper.com/static/images/er5.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planwlpaper.com/static/images/3col.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planaper.com/sttic/images/fghdfg.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.pwalper.com/sttic/imaes/3dsfgdg45.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planwallpaper.com/static/images/34rt5.png" alt="org"></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.planwaaper.com/static/images/7004205-cool-black-backgrounds-27640_lhK8IKI.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <div><img class="myimage" src="http://www.wallpeast.com/wallpaper-cool/page/4#static/images/free-cool-wallpaper-17426-18158-hd-wallpapers.jpg" alt=""></div>
  <script>  
  /*
    for(var i=0; i<document.getElementsByTagName("img").length; i++) {      
      document.getElementsByTagName("img")[i].addEventListener("error", function() {
        this.src = "https://cdn.colorlib.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/404-not-found-error-page-examples.png";        
      });      
    }
    */   
  </script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script> 
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".myimage").on("error", function(){      
      $(this).attr( "src", "http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/error-icon-28.png" );  
    });
  });

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How will that make any difference at all?